# How to parse the text to get all mentionees?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I would like to parse a text to get array of mentioneess from that text :

```
class Mentionee
  attr_reader :id, :display_name

  def initialize(id:, display_name:)
    @id = id
    @display_name = display_name
  end

  def self.parse(text)
     # ???
  end
end

mentionees = Mentionee.parse('[1:John C.] [2: Smith X.] you are awesome!')
mentioneess[0].id            # => '1'
mentioneess[0].display_name  # => 'John C.'
mentioneess[1].id            # => '2'
mentioneess[1].display_name  # => 'Smith X.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would help you.

```
> '[1:John C.] [2: Smith X.] you are awesome!'.scan(/(?<=\[)(\d+)(?=:\s*([^\]]+))/)
=> [["1", "John C."], ["2", "Smith X."]]
```

Comment: Look like missing name still match `[1:]`?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you want to parse text passed to method `parse`

```
  def self.parse(text)
    text.scan(/\[(.*?):(.*?)\]/).map do |e|
      {id: e[0], display_name: e[1]}
    end
  end
```

Will produce:

```
[
  {id: "1", display_name: "John C."},
  {id: "2", display_name: "Smith X."}
]
```

and you will be able to use as you described

```
mentionees = Mentionee.parse('[1:John C.] [2: Smith X.] you are awesome!')
mentioneess[0][:id]            # => 1
mentioneess[0][:display_name]  # => 'John C.'
mentioneess[1][:id]            # => 2
mentioneess[1][:display_name]  # => 'Smith X.'
```

Comment: Look like missing name still match `'[1:] [2: Smith X.] you are awesome!'`?

Comment: Is it problem if it matches? do you want to prevent it?